# How to implement regexp negation in SQLite?

Tags: regex, sqlite

I am looking to implement the negation of a regular expression using SQLite, using postgresql as a reference. Can this be done?

E.g. if i want to implement this statement:

```
case when keyword !~ '.*Brand*' then 'non brand user' end
```

I tried unsuccessfully:

```
case when keyword !REGEXP '.*Brand*' then 'non brand user' end
```

This is a simplified example. I am aware of the 'like' operator and using it would involve a lot of work to implement compared to regexp.

Comment: I figured out that it can be done using NOT REGEXP

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have any built in regex support, thought it may be possible to include it.  However, I think `NOT LIKE` might already do what you need:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN keyword NOT LIKE '%Brand%' THEN 'non brand user' END AS status
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: sqlite includes regular expression support with the REGEXP keyword. https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp

Comment: @Wedgwood Maybe this has changed, but last I checked you needed to install `REGEXP` in SQLite, it doesn't come with it automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Based on OP's answer to their own question, the solution is to use `NOT REGEXP`

```
case when keyword NOT REGEXP '.*Brand*' then 'non brand user' end
```